# "you cannot vote again after retracting": applies to just that question?

Tags: support, feature-request

When attempting to retract a close vote, one is asked to confirm the retraction with a message saying: "you cannot vote again after retracting". That applies just to the specific question, yes? Just checking in case retracting a vote is a bigger deal than I realize.

Regardless the answer, perhaps the message could be improved to be more clear. For example:
"you cannot vote again on this question after retracting"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it pertains to just that individual question. You will still be able to vote on other questions.

A similar (but not identical) question was asked on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332817/replace-you-already-voted-to-close-after-retracting-vote) almost a year ago. Unfortunately, it received no answers.

Comment: Is there a guideline regarding when to search Meta versus P&T-Meta?

Comment: @Aaron If your question applies to every SE site, I'd say that Meta is the best place for it. Put another way, if your question could feasibly be put on every single SE's individual meta page, then the larger Meta is probably where you'd find it (or want to ask it). But if it involves any specifics of a particular SE page—like what's on topic, or a particular post—I'd say look to the individual site's meta first.